# ANTD: Form.Item with Select - How can I added object value for one Option

Tags: reactjs, antd

I know than tag option can carry multiple values:

```
<option value={key1:value1, key2:value2}></option>
```

but in ANTD I tried to do the same but got an error.
Is there another way to send multiple value from select option?
My code looks like this

```
<Form.Item name={something}> 
     {list.map(option => 
          <Option value{{key1:option.one}, {key2:option.two}/>
      )}
</Form.Item>
```

Comment: Hey RoseMary.. i think you didn't close } in the value..
<Form.Item name={something}> 
     {list.map(option => 
          <Option value{{key1:option.one}, {key2:option.two}}/>
      )}
</Form.Item>